# How can I ensure width of react semantic UI component stays within viewport?

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui

I am using the Table component and want the table to responsively resize with the window horizontally only instead of overflowing and using the arrow keys to view the whole thing.

This is my current implementation:

```
<Container key={iterator}fluid>
          <Table celled padded>
            <Table.Body>
                {inner}
            </Table.Body>
          </Table>
      </Container>;
```

where inner can be any arbitrary size table that I am creating.

Comment: Have you tried making the table `stackable`?